# First Order Logic - unsatisfiable clause

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

My prof. said that using the language of definite programs, it is not possible to construct contradictory descriptions, i.e. unsatisfiable sets of formulas.

However, since a definite program can consist in only one clause. We can take the clause $p(x)$.
Now, if $p(x)$ is false for every object of every domain, this clause is unsatisfiable. Am i wrong ?

Comment: A single clause $p(x)$ (i.e. an *atomic* formula) cannot be unsatisfiable. We can interpret it in the domain $\mathbb N$ and interpret $x$ as $2$ and $p(x)$ as "$x$ is *even*".

Comment: Right. Thanks :)))

Comment: If you write it as an answer i can select is  as useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single clause (i.e. an *atomic* formula) $p(x)$ cannot be unsatisfiable.

We can interpret it in the domain $\mathbb N$ and interpret $x$ as $2$ and $p(x)$ as "$x$ is *even*".